# Extracting emails via web scraping python not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can someone help me write the part of the code which extracts the emails from the following HTML via BeautifulSoup? I tried the

1. `select` method
2. `find` method
3. `find_all` method

The HTML:

```
<div id="google_ads_div_990x50-Top_Bar-Classified_Detail_ad_wrapper">
<div id="google_ads_div_990x50-Top_Bar-Classified_Detail_ad_container" style="display:inline-block;">
<div id="top-bar-branding">
<div id="top-bar-branding-logo" style="margin-right:20px margin-left:6px">
<div id="top-bar-branding-text" style="color:#000; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; width:450px; text-align:center">As we promised</div>
<div id="top-bar-branding-extra" style="color:#000; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">
<span style="color:#444; font-weight:normal;">Telephone </span>
04 451 3111
<span style="color:#444; font-weight:normal;">or email </span>
<span style="color:#cf3023;"> info@home4all.ae</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I'm trying this but gives an empty list, `[]`:

```
email=soup.select("div #top-bar-branding-extra color:#cf3023;")
print email
```

This also doesn't work:

```
div = soup.find("div", {"id":"top-bar-branding-extra"})
span = div.find("span", {"style":"color:#cf3023;"})
print span.string
```

Comment: Do you have a URL for that page so I can verify the actual source?

Comment: http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/

Comment: That div is loaded by javascript, it is **not** part of the original source page.

Comment: Sorry. this is the right url http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2014/3/16/fully-furnished-2br-for-rent-in-dubai-gate-2/?back=ZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUuY29tL3Byb3BlcnR5LWZvci1yZW50L3Jlc2lkZW50aWFsL2FwYXJ0bWVudGZsYXQv&pos=1

Answer (score 1):

The `.select()` method only takes CSS *selectors* (tag names, ids, classes, and other CSS selector syntax), not whole CSS *declarations* (no contents of the `style` attribute); you'd search for:

```
soup.select('div#top-bar-branding-extra span')
```

as you cannot search for the `style` attribute with CSS here. You could then further filter on the matched elements:

```
for span in soup.select('div#top-bar-branding-extra span'):
    if span.get('style') == 'color:#cf3023;':
        email = span.text
        break
```

or make that a generator expression, defaulting to `None`:

```
email = next((s.text for s in soup.select('div#top-bar-branding-extra span')
              if s.get('style') == 'color:#cf3023;'), None)
```

but you need to look at the actual page source (not the browser DOM representation) to see if that matches closely enough to the actual attribute text.

If your posted HTML source is accurate, the above works:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div id="google_ads_div_990x50-Top_Bar-Classified_Detail_ad_wrapper">
... <div id="google_ads_div_990x50-Top_Bar-Classified_Detail_ad_container" style="display:inline-block;">
... <div id="top-bar-branding">
... <div id="top-bar-branding-logo" style="margin-right:20px margin-left:6px">
... <div id="top-bar-branding-text" style="color:#000; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; width:450px; text-align:center">As we promised</div>
... <div id="top-bar-branding-extra" style="color:#000; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">
... <span style="color:#444; font-weight:normal;">Telephone </span>
... 04 451 3111
... <span style="color:#444; font-weight:normal;">or email </span>
... <span style="color:#cf3023;"> info@home4all.ae</span>
... </div>
... </div>
... </div>
... </div>
... </div>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> for span in soup.select('div#top-bar-branding-extra span'):
...     if span.get('style') == 'color:#cf3023;':
...         email = span.text
...         break
... 
>>> email
u' info@home4all.ae'
>>> email = next((s.text for s in soup.select('div#top-bar-branding-extra span')
...               if s.get('style') == 'color:#cf3023;'), None)
>>> email
u' info@home4all.ae'
```

Note that this requires that the *actual source loaded* from your URL contains this structure. Judging by the HTML, you are trying to load an email from a Google ad on the page, which is always loaded *via JavaScript*, and is not part of the original source.

You'd have to analyze how Google is loading the advertisements and replicate that in Python, or use a full web client (like [ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) or a selenium-driven browser) to execute the Javascript, retrieve the resulting DOM and then parse *that* instead.

Comment: i doesnt give any result for me:(

Comment: That's because you are trying to match Javascript-generated HTML, your soup doesn't actually contain that structure.

Comment: http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2014/3/16/fully-furnished-2br-for-rent-in-dubai-gate-2/?back=ZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUuY29tL3Byb3BlcnR5LWZvci1yZW50L3Jlc2lkZW50aWFsL2FwYXJ0bWVudGZsYXQv&pos=1 try this please

Comment: Not for me it isn't; I see *place an ad (free)* instead.

Comment: just skip it and the page will appear

Comment: But that's not the point, the point is that *that section is dynamic*. It is *not part of the page you loaded*.

Comment: yes its dynamic. i am running the pages in a loop. i

Comment: @user3265370: The last URL indeed has Google advertisements, but the whole `google_ads_div_300x250-ROS-Top_ad_wrapper` div is loaded from JavaScript; Google code loaded from http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js and/or http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads

Comment: every sec a new page appears and the program is extracting it. i am getting 13 more information such as bedrooms, size etc. each time its different and the database is saving it